# Why changes to the outer data-source is not reflected, while they show-up for the inner data-source?

Tags: c#, linq

Why changes to the outer data-source is not reflected, while they show-up for the inner data-source?? Pls help

```
public static void MyMethod(char[] inputDS1, char[] inputDS2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n'from' clause - Display all possible combinations of a-b-c-d.");

    //query syntax
    IEnumerable<ChrPair> resultset = from res1 in inputDS1
                                     from res2 in inputDS2
                                     select new ChrPair(res1, res2);

    //Write result-set
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nOutput list -->");
    displayList(resultset);

    //swap positions
    //obs: changes to the first ds is not reflected in the resultset.
    char[] temp = inputDS1;
    inputDS1 = inputDS2;
    inputDS2 = temp;

    //run query again
    displayList(resultset);
    Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------------");
}
```

Input:

```
('a','b'), ('c','d')
```

Output:

```
ac, ad, bc, bd, **aa. ab, ba, bb**
```

I expected all possible combinations (ac, ad, bc, bd, **ca, cb, da, db**) as I swapped the Data-sources before the second Write. When I do a ToList() before the second Write, I get the expected result, so is it because that Select is lazy? Please explain.

**Update**

What I tried was - to add a ToList() (to force immediate execution) to the query-expression after the ds-swap. And I got the proper results - ac, ad, bc, bd, ca, cb, da, db.
This would return expected results.

```
//query syntax
IEnumerable<ChrPair> resultset = from res1 in inputDS1
                                from res2 in inputDS2
                                select new ChrPair(res1, res2);

//Write result-set
Console.WriteLine("\n\nOutput list -->");
displayList(resultset);

//swap positions
//obs: changes to the first ds is not reflected in the resultset.
char[] temp = inputDS1;
inputDS1 = inputDS2;
inputDS2 = temp;

resultset = (from res1 in inputDS1
            from res2 in inputDS2
            select new ChrPair(res1, res2)).ToList();

//run query again
displayList(resultset);
```

Comment: Interesting question :) I would have expected both datasources to be captured. It seems only the second one is.

Comment: It appears this is how the LINQ is transformed. To 'fix' it, add `from _ in "_"` at the start of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast response - leppie. Please could you elaborate "add from _ in "_"". Also, I just edited my post to show what I had to do to get the desired results.

Comment: In the update edit, you reconstruct the query, and it gets bound to the new value of `inputDS1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the issue is that the first variable (inputDS1) don't included in any anonymous function (lambda) then the compiler wouldn't generate closure for it.

Compiler translates query to something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ChrPair> resultset = 
    inputDS1.SelectMany(c => inputDS2.Select(c1 => new ChrPair(c, c1)));
```

As you see, the `inputDS1`is not contains in any anonymous(lambda). Instead, the `inputDS2` contains in lambda then compiler will generate for it closure. Therefore, in your second execution of query you have access to modified closure `inputDS2`.

Comment: Please could you add a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

what you got were combination from chars from `inputDS1` with chars from `inputDS2`. this is what the query

```
    IEnumerable<ChrPair> resultset = from res1 in inputDS1
                                     from res2 in inputDS2
                                     select new ChrPair(res1, res2);
```

does, that's what you asked from it: "take 1 item from `inputDS1` and 1 item from `inputDS2` and combine the two to `new ChrPair`"

**EDIT**

after understanding your question let me explain something very fundamental:

the line

```
    IEnumerable<ChrPair> resultset = from res1 in inputDS1
                                     from res2 in inputDS2
                                     select new ChrPair(res1, res2);
```

does not return a list or `IEnumerable<ChrPair>`. it return a method that has a source (`inputDS1`) and an input. when you're swapping the two, you mess with the input of the method, but the source does not changed (it probably copied and not just referenced). when you do `.ToList();` you activate the method, thus not getting any unexpected behavior due to commands called afterwards.

Comment: Yes, but I changed inputDss just before I executed the query second time... and was expecting (ac, ad, bc, bd, ca, cb, da, db) but got (ac, ad, bc, bd, aa. ab, ba, bb) instead. So - wanted to know what was happening in the backgroud.... hope I`m making sense..

Comment: @SUMITCHATTERJEE i understand now your question and know where you have mistaken, it got nothing to do with toList. you can remove it and it still works(checked that). lemme edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, the part

```
char[] temp = inputDS1;
    inputDS1 = inputDS2;
    inputDS2 = temp;
```

swaps around the input parameter and not the results you get from your linq statement.